# OpenLayers: 'Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement'

Tags: javascript, canvas, dictionary, openlayers-3, wms

I have a problem  when I try to export a map with multiple layer created using OpenLayer.
This is my JS code:

```
map.once('postcompose', function(event) {
       var img = new Image,
       canvas = event.context.canvas;

       img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
       img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
});
```

Where **map** is the JavaScript variable of my OpenLayers map.
When the map is composed of more than one level, I receive this kind of error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on
>   'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

If a try to do the same thing without adding level to the map (just using the default OpenLayer map) I am able to generate the data URL and download the map in png format.
**It seems to be a CrossOrigin problem, but the CORs should be enabled on my server.**
Any help? Thanks!

**EDIT**
Here it is the JS code example where I add the layer to the map that is causing this issues.

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Image({
     source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'http://pubblicazioni.provincia.fi.it/geoserver/wms',
        params: {
                'LAYERS': 'layer_name',
                'FORMAT': 'image/png',
                'TRANSPARENT': 'true'
        },
        crossOrigin: null
     })
});
map.addLayer(layer);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `crossOrigin: ''` on the source of your tile layer (like in this [example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/icon.html))?

Comment: I tried to set crossOrigin: 'Anonymous', but in that case I wasn't able to load the layer on the map due security error. I will try with your suggestion.

Comment: When I use `crossOrigin: ''` I recevive this kind of error:
`Image from origin 'http://pubblicazioni.provincia.fi.it' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://188.166.72.87' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem implementing a local proxy on my server as suggested by MichaelJS.
I'm running a Django app, so I developed a customized proxy starting from this code:
https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-proxy

Then in my urls.py I defined this rule:

```
url(r'^proxy/(?P<url>.*)$', views.proxy_view, name='proxy'),
```

And finally I proxed the request to the WMS service changing the JS code this way:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Image({
     source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: '/proxy/http://pubblicazioni.provincia.fi.it/geoserver/wms',
        params: {
                'LAYERS': 'layer_name',
                'FORMAT': 'image/png',
                'TRANSPARENT': 'true'
        },
        crossOrigin: null
     })
});
map.addLayer(layer);
```

**CrossOrigin issue solved!**

Answer (score 2):

You can look at [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) to see CORS settings.  Instead of setting crossOrigin in your source to `''`, you can try setting it to anonymous:

```
crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I cant comment yet, my answer here
The solutions is 
a) set up a local proxy and receive the data with its help 
b) ask the source-provider if he can activate Cross-Origin-Allow-Header "*".

Answer (score 0):

This can be happens,when you load the wms layers images into the map but this wms layers loads some CORS insecure third-party images. it is security behaviors of from the browser which disable downloading of the tainted image. To avoid having tainted canvas put              `crossOrigin: "anonymous"` this line into your base map. See following example:

```
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'Périmètres des PPR Inondation',
        type: 'base',
        visible: false,
        zIndex: 1000,
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: wmsperi,
        params: {'LAYERS': 'PPRN_PERIMETRE_INOND', 'TILED': true, 'CRS': 'EPSG:3857'},
        crossOrigin: "anonymous"
        })
```